A sequence such that $(a_{n+1} - a_n )\rightarrow \infty $ but $(\sqrt{a_{n+1}} -\sqrt{a_n} )\rightarrow 0$
Does there exist a sequence $( a_n )_{n\ge 1}$  of positive real numbers such that $\lim _{n \rightarrow \infty}(a _{n+1}-a_n) =\infty  $ and
$\lim _{n \rightarrow \infty}(\sqrt{a _{n+1}}-\sqrt{a_n}) =0  $   ?
I was thinking along this line :-
$(a _{n+1}-a_n)=   (\sqrt{a _{n+1}}-\sqrt{a_n} )  (\sqrt{a _{n+1}}+\sqrt{a_n} ) =\frac 1{2^n}*3^n $
But succesive calculations to get $a_n$ gives no conclusions .
A trivial observations is $a_n$ must properly diverge to infinity . The answer is given to be yes. How may I proceed?

$a_n=n^{3/2}$ should work

$\sqrt{a_n}= \sum\limits_{k=1}^n \frac{1}{\sqrt{n}}$ so $\sqrt{a_{n+1}}- \sqrt{a_n} =\frac{1}{\sqrt{n+1}} \to 0$ and $a_{n+1}-a_n =(\sqrt{a_{n+1}}-\sqrt{a_n} )(\sqrt{a_{n+1}}+\sqrt{a_n} ) \approx \frac{4(n^{3/2})}{3\sqrt{n+1}}\to \infty$

If $a_n=n^b$, with $1<b<2$, then by virtue of MVT, there exist a $\xi_n\in(0,1),$ s.t.
$$
a_{n+1}-a_n=(n+1)^b-n^b=b(n+\xi_n)^{b-1}>bn^{b-1}\to \infty,
$$
while
$$
0<a_{n+1}^{1/2}-a_n^{½}=(n+1)^{b/2}-n^{b/2}=\frac{b}{2}(n+\xi_n)^{b/2-1}=
\frac{b}{2(n+\xi_n)^{1-b/2}}
<\frac{b}{2n^{1-b/2}} \to 0
$$
